# Command Line Argument for Script Changing Way Code Functions

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing a script to loop through a directory, look through each file, and give the iterations of a certain word in each file. When I write it for the specific directory it works fine, but when I try to make the directory a command line argument, it only gives me the count for the first file. I was thinking maybe this has something to do with, the argument being singular ($1), but I really have no idea.

Works

```
for f in /home/student/Downloads/reviews_folder/*
do
    tr -s ' ' '\n' <$f | grep -c '<Author>'
done
```

Output

```
125
163
33
...
```

Doesn't Work

```
for f in "$1"
do
    tr -s ' ' '\n' <$f | grep -c '<Author>'
done
```

Command Line Input

```
student-vm:~$ ./countreviews.sh /home/student/Downloads/reviews_folder/*
```

Output

```
125
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell expands wildcards before passing the list of arguments to your script.

To loop over all the files passed in as command-line arguments,

```
for f in "$@"
do
    tr -s ' ' '\n' <"$f" | grep -c '<Author>'
done
```

Run it like

```
./countreviews /home/student/Downloads/reviews_folder/*
```

or more generally

```
./countreviews ... list of file names ...
```

As you discovered, `"$1"` corresponds to the first file name in the expanded list of wildcards.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using double quotes for the parameter it should work. Like this:

```
student-vm:~$ ./countreviews.sh "/home/student/Downloads/reviews_folder/*"
```

At least like this it works for me. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Erm, no, it doesn't work at all, unless you have a file named literally `*` in that directory.

Comment: It *could* "work", if you left `$1` unquoted in the script (since the expansion would undergo pathname expansion), but then you are also subject to unintended word-splitting, so you're just trading one problem for another.